# SIGABRT  in simple iPhone application

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm doing a very simple application that has two buttons, one label and one text field; the first button copies the text field's text to the label and the second button cleans both. When I execute I have this error:
Program recieved signal: "SIGABRT"

Where is the problem?

Thanks.

```
ViewController.m:

@synthesize myInput, myLabel, button1, button2;

- (IBAction)boton1Pressed:(id)sender {
[self.myLabel setText:[self.myInput text]]; 
}

- (IBAction) boton2Pressed:(id)sender {
[self.myLabel setText:[NSString stringWithString:@""]];
}

ViewController.h:

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myInput;

- (IBAction)boton1Pressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)boton2Pressed:(id)sender;
(...)
```

Comment: Check your references for actions and outlets in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1):

The error isn't in the code, i think.

Check the connections of the file .xib against outlets of your ViewController.

You probably have a problem with any connection to any outlet old, you have created or you accidentally deleted.

Regards,

Ángel.

Answer (score 0):

You also aren't synthesizing your accessors in the ViewController.m file. Or at least, not as far as we can see from the code posted.

```
@synthesize myLabel, myInput;
```

Comment: You need to double check your connections in IB as beryllium already said.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code... And dont forget to link them with Xib.... and i have tested it you dont forget to accept it.. :)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MayankViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIButton *btn1,*btn2;
    IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtField;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btn1;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btn2;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *txtField;

-(IBAction) onTapBtn1;
-(IBAction) onTapBtn2;
@end







#import "MayankViewController.h"

@implementation MayankViewController

@synthesize btn1,btn2,lbl,txtField;

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(IBAction) onTapBtn1
{
    lbl.text = txtField.text;
}

-(IBAction) onTapBtn2
{
    lbl.text = @"";
    txtField.text = @"";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [btn1 release];
    [btn2 release];
    [lbl release];
    [txtField release];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

@synthesize is not a problem at all. If you don't access the object from other class, where is the need of synthesizing getters and setters ?? You also don't need to use 'self' every time. This line may be wrong :

> [self.myInput text]

rather, use myInput.text.

Comment: It is unless you want compiler warnings.